# Dictionary software which allows to add or edit entries

Tags: windows, offline, dictionary

I want a dictionary software which allows me to add or edit entries, words or meanings.

I want to use it on Windows. It has to work offline.

It is best to be freeware but others will be accepted.

Comment: Try My Word List. Not for Windows, but offline. You get over 800,000 words and can save your words and add notes: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simone.mywordlist